# Core Data entity naming convention

Tags: ios, core-data

Is there a convention for naming Core Data entity?  The [argument](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.07/CoreData/index.html) I heard for not prefixing Core Data entity is because there is no chance they will be collision since they only need to be unique within a model, which is not true because the NSManagedObject subclass generated may still collide with existing Objective-C classes.

So it seems logical for me to do two things to Core Data Entity: Prefix it with my project class prefix, and suffix it with Entity.  This way, I know it's a Core Data entity, and its name will never collide with any other classes.

Comment: The class name and entity name do not have to be the same.

Comment: True, but that is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually seen both prefixing with the project class prefix and without.  I have never seen a suffix being added.  I prefer without the project prefix, since if you have a remote database that you are syncing up with, I would use the same entity names.  And then if you ever release a public API, do you really want your project prefix all over the place?  For example, Stripe's entities are Customer, Card, etc.  They use the prefix in the unique identifiers, which I like.  Also, if you are using the project prefix for your other classes, you do not run the risk of overwriting, like you mention in your OP.

Comment: Good point on remote database, though with the remote database is even though the name may be the same, often times the entity attributes still do not match up with the database fields.  For example, attributes in Core Data use camelCase, whereas a remote database may use camel_case.

Comment: that drives me crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

From here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

> You cannot give an accessor a name that begins with new. This in turn means that you can’t, for example, declare a property whose name begins with new unless you specify a different getter

And as far as I know also copy keyword cant be used as suffix.